# How do I limit a text input form to a certain range of values with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

So what I am trying to do is make it so the input field can not go below a certain value.

My input field is a normal:

```
<input id="something">
```

my javascript is:

```
(function () {
    int statesMin = 50000;
    int statesMax = 500000;
    var val = $('#something').val();
    var int = parseInt(((val * 100)/100), 10); //This is to change my text into an integer
    if(val < statesMin) {
    return false;
    }
    if(val > statesMax) {
    return false;
    }

    return true;
})();
```

I am using jQuery Validation plugin if that helps. All I really want is if the input is 40,000; then I want it to say no that won't work. I've heard of "listening for a blur event" but I don't really know what that means. Is there anyway someone could help me on this. How to I have that input check to see if the text inputted validates that function I created.

Comment: why don't you just use maxlength and minlength?

Comment: `parseInt(((val * 100)/100), 10)` is overkill, `+val` will do.

Comment: And a <input placeholder='input 0-40'> Or whatever. then the user also can see what values are expected

Comment: @EL3PHANTEN—placeholders should not be used as screen tips. The tip is lost once the user focuses on the input or starts typing (depending on the browser) and they can no longer see the tip.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_text_autonext

Comment: `blur` is when the focus is released from that element. You want to use `$("#selector").blur(function () { ... do whatever here ...})`

Comment: @RobG what does +val mean? How do I use that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TR3eP/)

use `blur` so it triggers when the input box loses focus

```
  $('#something').on('blur',function(){
    var statesMin = 50000;
    var statesMax = 500000; 
    var val = $('#something').val();
    if(val < statesMin) {
    alert("Wont work");
        return false;
    }
    if(val > statesMax) {
       alert("Wont work");
        return false;
    }

    return true;

});
```

Comment: Is there a way instead of using the alert(); to use jQuery validation to send a manual error message out? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Solution #1:**

```
minlength="50000"
maxlength="500000"

<input id="Check" type="checkbox"/>
<input id="something" type="text"/>
```

**Solution 2: (Alert)**

```
$('#something').focusout(function(){
    var Min = 5;
    var Max = 50; 
    var value = $('#something').val();
    if(val < Min) {
        alert("Try Again");
        return false;
    }
    else if(val > Max) {
        alert("Try Again");
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
});
```

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/E726S/6

Comment: Thanks for that edition, but I also want to know how to get the function to trigger upon a button being submitted, like a validation..

Comment: Editing for an easy solution :)

Answer (score 0):

This code will simply restrict the value of the field to the allowed range, keeping the value on min and max if it is greater or lower of it.

```
var $field = $( '#something' ),
    min = 10, 
    max = 100;
$field
    .on( 'keyup', function ( e ) {
        if ( parseInt( $field.val() ) < min ) {
            $field.val( min );
        } else if ( parseInt( $field.val() ) > max ) {
            $field.val( max );
        } 
    } );
```

---

If you want to use this as a validation function:

```
$( 'form' ).on( 'submit', function ( e ) {
    if ( parseInt( $field.val() ) < min ) {
        alert( 'Number too low.' );
    } else if ( parseInt( $field.val() ) > max ) {
        alert( 'Number too high.' );
    } 
} );
```

Comment: Question: So I am also using the jQuery number plugin where it will add in commas and what not. So basically its kinda of freaking out and won't let me type anything when I do the key up feature. I was wondering if you could help. So I used your above code.. and then I used this for JS for number plugin --         (function(){ var $calc = $('calculator'), $something = $calc.find('annuity_premium'); $annuity.number(true, 2, '.', ',');    -- I was wondering if you knew how to get it from stop freaking out, because if I could get this to work then you have helped me hugely :)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is a way to check `<input>`s once the user has deselected them. The ideal event handler for this would be [`blur`](http://api.jquery.com/blur/). You can also use one of the key press event handlers ([keypress](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/), [keyup](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/), and [keydown](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/)). These would be good if you want to run a function every time the input is changed (aka while the user is typing).

## [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Luxelin/S92d8/3/)

I've made a short demo for you:

**HTML**

```
<input id="checkme">
<p id="results"></p>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$("#checkme").blur(function () {
    var value = parseInt($(this).val().replace(/[^\d]+/g, "")),
        // this grabs only the numbers from the input
        // by parsing for integers of
        // $(this).val() ---> this grabs the value of the input#checkme
        // .replace(/[^\d]+/g, "") is a regular expression
        // that replaces all characters that are not digits (0-9) with "", or nothing
        // this is, of course, all wrapped in the parseInt call, so that
        // value is always a number
        min = 20,    // I made up some min/max values
        max = 100;
    if (value < min || value > max) {
        // the input doesn't match what you want
        $("#results").text("That number is no bueno!");
        $("#checkme").removeClass("bueno").addClass("nobueno");
    } else {
        // the input does match what you want
        $("#results").text("bueno!");
        $("#checkme").removeClass("nobueno").addClass("bueno");
    }
})
```

**CSS**

```
.bueno {
    border: solid 1px green;
}
.nobueno {
    border: solid 1px red;
}
```

The general idea is to, either on `keypress` or on `blur`, validate the input (run it through some function — in this case, I've checked whether it is in a given range) and then notify the user. If you want to tell people that `40,000` doesn't work, then write a function appropriate to your needs and have it run after the user has entered the input. If this is a form, make sure to validate it before it is sent off (and on the server too). Otherwise, you should be fine.

---

If you want to call a function to check `input#checkme` on a button click, you can do the following:

```
$("#buttonID").click(function () {
    var value = $("#inputID").val();

    // run it through whatever function you want
})
```

It seems you're new to jQuery and JavaScript. I'd really advise reading the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com) — it's more helpful than you'd think. I would suggest starting with [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), since that's what you seem to have trouble with. There are, of course, a ton of other guides you can look into, such as [Crockford's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246/best-resources-to-learn-javascript). Some people seem to hate him, others love him. I don't know. There are a ton of other resources too, you just need to search around.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one..

```
<form id="frm" action="Default.aspx" method="post">
        <input type="text" id="something" />
        <input type="submit" onclick="return validate();" value="submit" />
    </form>


function validate() {
            var ret = true;
            var statesMin = 50000;
            var statesMax = 500000;
            var val = $('#something').val();
            var int = parseInt(((val * 100) / 100), 10);
            if (val < statesMin) {
                alert('This is error');
                ret = false;
            }
            else if (val > statesMax) {
                alert('This is error');
                ret = false;
            }

            return ret;
        };
```

in order to validate before you submit use this `onclick="return validate();"` to return whether true or false.

I hope this will help you